# How can I get a value for a column that is not contained in a group by (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that contains three columns (`Name, Value, Date`) and I need to get the latest value for each names.

This is the complete table :

```
Name   | Value | Date  
-------+-------+-----------
aaaaa  | 1     | 01-01-2018  
bbbbb  | 2     | 02-01-2018  
aaaaa  | 2     | 03-01-2018
bbbbb  | 1     | 04-01-2018
```

This is the result I need :

```
Name   | Value | Date  
-------+-------+-----------
aaaaa  | 2     | 03-01-2018
bbbbb  | 1     | 04-01-2018
```

I tried a few things (group by, over(partition), ...) but I cannot figure how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use window function

```
select * from 
(select *, row_number over(partition by name order by date desc) as rn
) t where rn=1
```

or co-related sub-query

```
select * from t t1
where t.date in (select max(date) from t where t2.name=t1.name group by t2.name)
```

or you can use

```
select TOP(1) with ties *
from t 
order by (row_number() over(partition by name order by date DESC));
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly with the window function !

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number() funtion:

```
select * from 
(
select name, value, row_number() over(partition by name order by date desc) as rn
)a where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

With an index on `(name, date)`, this would often have the better performance than other methods.